# 3 phase generator coil winding testing

Tags: generator, testing

can some one help in testing methods of the stator and coil windings?

[image: coil]
[image: genset]

Comment: This has been on here before.

Comment: lara - The community decided that this question was an off-topic repair question [when you asked it before](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/566806/3-phase-generator-help-testing-methods). Therefore, unless community members vote to re-open *that* question, then the decision stands. You're probably better looking for a repair *forum*.  This site doesn't try to be one of those. (Also, repeating the same question is classed as "noise" here, so please don't do that.) Thanks.

Comment: "The community" or a few people?

Comment: asking about testing method is now allowed as a topic... wow...

Comment: never asked HOW TO REPAIR..... i asked about testing methods.